# Equivalent lambda syntax for linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a mind-freeze here, but I cant seem to find the equivalent lambda syntax for -

```
string[] a = {"a","b","c"}; 
string[] b = {"1","2","3"}; 

var x = from a1 in a
        from b1 in b
        select new{a1, b1};
```

Comment: For your future reference, the rules for how to determine equivalent syntaxes for all LINQ queries are found in section 7.16.2 of the C# 4 specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = a.SelectMany(a1=>b.Select(b1=>new {a1,b1}));
```

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper says:

```
var x = a.SelectMany(a1 => b, (a1, b1) => new { a1, b1 });
```